# SQL Server and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to take data from an MS SQL server 2005 table and insert it into a linked MySQL table, my query is bellow but it is not working. I keep getting "Query Executed successfully, 0 Rows Affected". Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(WEBSITE, 'SELECT SalesID,Cust,OrderDate,PONum,PartNo,QTY,PartDesc,DiscPct,DueDate,ShipCity,ShipSt,OrderStatus,InvoiceNo,InvDate,OrderTotal FROM orders')
SELECT Orders.SalesID, Orders.CustDesc, Orders.DateEnt, Orders.PONum, OrderDet.PartNo, OrderDet.QtyOrdered, OrderDet.PartDesc, OrderDet.DiscPct, OrderDet.DueDate, Orders.ShipCity, Orders.ShipSt, OrderDet.Status, BillingDet.InvoiceNo, Billing.InvDate, Orders.OrderTotal
FROM Orders INNER JOIN OrderDet ON (Orders.OrderNo = OrderDet.OrderNo)
LEFT JOIN BillingDet ON (Orders.PONum = BillingDet.PONum)
LEFT JOIN Billing ON (BillingDET.InvoiceNo = Billing.InvoiceNo)
WHERE OrderDet.PartNo LIKE '%^%' AND Orders.DateEnt >='2011/12/31'
```

Comment: and what's the error message?

Comment: No error message it says query completed successfully. that's the problem, it completes but does not actually insert....

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want to insert into `WEBSITE...orders` try this:

```
INSERT  INTO WEBSITE...orders
        (
          SalesID,
          Cust,
          OrderDate,
          PONum,
          PartNo,
          QTY,
          PartDesc,
          DiscPct,
          DueDate,
          ShipCity,
          ShipSt,
          OrderStatus,
          InvoiceNo,
          InvDate,
          OrderTotal
        )
        SELECT  Orders.SalesID,
                Orders.CustDesc,
                Orders.DateEnt,
                Orders.PONum,
                OrderDet.PartNo,
                OrderDet.QtyOrdered,
                OrderDet.PartDesc,
                OrderDet.DiscPct,
                OrderDet.DueDate,
                Orders.ShipCity,
                Orders.ShipSt,
                OrderDet.Status,
                BillingDet.InvoiceNo,
                Billing.InvDate,
                Orders.OrderTotal
        FROM    Orders
        INNER JOIN OrderDet
                ON ( Orders.OrderNo = OrderDet.OrderNo )
        LEFT JOIN BillingDet
                ON ( Orders.PONum = BillingDet.PONum )
        LEFT JOIN Billing
                ON ( BillingDET.InvoiceNo = Billing.InvoiceNo )
        WHERE   OrderDet.PartNo LIKE '%^%'
                AND Orders.DateEnt >= '2011/12/31'
```

Comment: Just run the select without the insert and make sure it actually returns data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO WEBSITE...orders(SalesID, Cust, OrderDate, PONum, PartNo, QTY, PartDesc, DiscPct, DueDate,
ShipCity, ShipSt, OrderStatus, InvoiceNo, InvDate, OrderTotal)
SELECT O.SalesID, O.CustDesc, O.DateEnt, O.PONum, OrderDet.PartNo,
OrderDet.QtyOrdered, OrderDet.PartDesc, OrderDet.DiscPct, OrderDet.DueDate,
O.ShipCity, O.ShipSt, OD.Status, BD.InvoiceNo, B.InvDate,
O.OrderTotal
FROM Orders O
    INNER JOIN OrderDet OD
        ON (O.OrderNo = OD.OrderNo)
    LEFT JOIN BillingDet BD
        ON (O.PONum = BD.PONum)
    LEFT JOIN Billing B
        ON (BD.InvoiceNo = B.InvoiceNo)
WHERE OD.PartNo LIKE '%^%'
    AND O.DateEnt >='2011/12/31'
```